# What do we know about the set of Primitive Dirichlet Characters modulu an integer $N$?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, finite-groups, dirichlet-convolution

I was working on Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions and I have the following question:

> Is the set of all Primitive Dirichlet Characters modulus some given (and fixed ) integer $N$ a ring for some known operations?

I tried some  operations like the product $\chi_1\chi_2$ or the convolution $\chi_1*\chi_2$, but I did not have any important results